# type miss match error in Worklight Studio

Tags: jquery, ibm-mobilefirst

when i am configuring jquery to the project file it showing type miss match error and my worklight version is 6.2

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to void  jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 143    JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from $.mobile.History to ___anonymous150913_150937    jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 4707   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from any[] to ___anonymous112373_112386   jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 3343   JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to ___anonymous431382_431402 jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 14246  JavaScript Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to ___anonymous385046_385348 jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  /danny/apps/karan/common/jqueryMobile   line 12599  JavaScript Problem
```

Comment: Your [1] link is missing

Comment: Provide your project. Upload it to Google Drive or Dropbox.

Comment: iam upload the project in google drive bro plz help me......

Comment: Provide link to your project

Comment: http://192.168.0.6:10080/worklightconsole/index.html#/runtimes/SANASW

Comment: @rabbanishaik, that's your internal IP address(!), we won't be able to access it... Extract the project from Eclipse and upload it as I instructed above.

Comment: thank u idar .iam showing my issue clearly...when am configure javascript libraries to the project it showing 100 warnings...am solve nearly 86 warnings...but i can't solve 14 errors that are type mismatch errors...this is my isssue you got it.

Comment: thank u all my issue is solved

Comment: @rabbanishaik, Please write the answer for this question.

Comment: @rabbanishaik, Why are you not responding?!

Answer (score 1):

The user did not bother to properly explain himself nor provided reproduction steps. Finally, he wrote the following:

when am configure javascript libraries

> to the project it showing 100 warnings...am solve nearly 86
>   warnings...but i can't solve 14 errors that are type mismatch
>   errors...this is my isssue you got it.

And then

> thank u all my issue is solved